# Теория: Вопрос о практическом применении OOP?

Tags: php, ооп, теория

Здравствуйте, в процессе изучения PHP меня всё также не покидает вопрос о практическом применении OOP. На данный момент, проанализировав свои работы, пришёл к выводу, что я не могу его на практике применить.

Складывается впечатление, что он пригоден при большом кол-ве однотипных переменных в плане разных данных и удобной классификации методов(функций) по действию. К примеру, данные о 3-ех авто - их цвет, скорость, растрата топлива. Но ведь и эти данные можно хранить в обычном массиве. Конечно, есть ещё конструкторы, деструкторы, наследования, но пока тоже особо практическое применение в голову не идёт.

Но ведь если есть альтернативы, так в чём суть OOP, и более того - почему он так популярен?

Думаю, многие задавались этим вопросом и нашли ответ, и прошу Вас этим ответом поделиться. Спасибо.

Comment: А вы не задумывались, для чего различные функции, можно же всё в одну?

Comment: С опытом придет понимание

Comment: @VladD, так и функции дублировать, по-сути, не надо. Всё в одну. Я о хранении данных в массиве в примере говорил. За ссылку спасибо Вам, почитаю.

Comment: @mJeevas, я это понимаю, у меня также с процедурным стилем сперва было, но там всё проще и через полчаса понятно было, а вот тут уже вечер весь сижу и думаю.

Answer (score 3):

Гради Буч сформулировал следующим образом:

> Объектно-ориентированные системы более открыты и легче поддаются
>   внесению изменений, поскольку их конструкция базируется на устойчивых
>   формах. Это дает возможность системе развиваться постепенно и не
>   приводит к полной ее переработке даже в случае существенных изменений
>   исходных требований.

Буч отмечает также ряд следующих преимуществ объектно- ориентированного подхода:

> 1. Объектная декомпозиция дает возможность создавать программные системы меньшего размера путем использования общих механизмов,
>      обеспечивающих необходимую экономию выразительных средств.
>      Использование объектного подхода существенно повышает уровень
>      унификации разработки и пригодность для повторного использования не
>      только программ, но и проектов, что в конце концов ведет к созданию
>      среды разработки и переходу к сборочному созданию ПО. Системы зачастую
>      получаются более компактными, чем их структурные эквиваленты, что
>      означает не только уменьшение объема программного кода, но и
>      удешевление проекта за счет использования предыдущих разработок.
> 2. Объектная декомпозиция уменьшает риск создания сложных систем ПО, так как она предполагает эволюционный путь развития системы на базе
>      относительно небольших подсистем. Процесс интеграции системы
>      растягивается на все время разработки, а не превращается в
>      единовременное событие.
> 3. Объектная модель вполне естественна, поскольку в первую очередь ориентирована на человеческое восприятие мира, а не на компьютерную
>      реализацию.

[Гради Буч](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%87,_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1):

> Думаю, многие задавались этим вопросом и нашли ответ, и прошу Вас этим
>   ответом поделиться.

Будучи в самом начале своего пути много раз слышал высказывания что нужно научится думать объектами, как таково требует парадигма, но не разу не слышал более сложного продолжения, что максимум что можно создать из объектов, это `коллекцию`.

Получается что нужно думать только объектами и только коллекциями. По этому мой совет - начните постижения не просто парадигмы, а самой идеи объектного программирования с создания всех видов коллекций.  Это покроет Ваши вопросы на 70%, ну а 20% из них придется приобрести после понимания и реализации `entity component system`, которая откроет Вам слой находящийся над коллекциями.

После этого я гарантирую что вопросы если и останутся, то будут закрываться моментально после прочтения более-менее внятных статей.
А до тех пор все статьи будут казаться чем-то из области астрономии - 
столь же далёким и чужим.

И помните - `сила в постижении ПРЕДМЕТНОЙ ОБЛАСТИ`.

Comment: линк на "про коллекции"?